# Create time course plot from tibble

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am sorry because this feels like it has a really obvious answer, but I am new to tidyverse and ggplot and I can't seem to find a useful solution.

The output of my data is a tibble, where the first column is `x`, which I want on my `x axis`, and then follow multiple columns of `y` and `z`.

Dummy data:

```
t1 <- tibble(x = 1:5, y = 1, z = x ^ 2 + y)
```

I now want to have `x` as my `x-axis`, with `y` and `z` being lines with different colours in the same plot. I know that that works, if I put `y` and `z` as descriptors below each other next to the corresponding x values as:

```
t2 <- tibble(x = c(1:5,1:5), a = c(rep(1,5),c(2,5,10,17,26)), b = c(rep("y",5), rep("z",5)))
ggplot(data = t2, aes(x = x, y = a, group = b, color = b))+
geom_line()
```

Now I want to know if there is a way to have the same result with `t1` or if there is a straightforward way to get to `t2`? Or do you have any pointers as to what I should search for?

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved via `tidyr::pivot_longer`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

t1 <- tibble(x = 1:5, y = 1, z = x ^ 2 + y)

t3 <- t1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "b", values_to = "a")

ggplot(data = t3, aes(x = x, y = a, group = b, color = b)) + geom_line()
```

[image]